# odometry opposite direction

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,i recently in SLAM, but there is a problem that bothers me deeply, I see in the RVIZ, the car Odometry in the opposite direction, when the car moves forward, odometer arrow nock will move forward, could someone be solved? Thank you very much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268385/odometry-opposite-direction/) by [zhangstar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31314/zhangstar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see two likely reasons for the issue:

1. Your rviz fixed frame is set to a non-standard frame. This could result in all sorts of "weird" motion displayed.
2. Odometry is indeed buggy and has a wrong sign or so.

You'll probably want to have a look at the output of

```
rostopic echo odom
```

and look at the raw numbers. You can update your question with this output, too.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhangstar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31314/zhangstar/) on 2017-08-10**:
hello!,i check the fixed frame ,it is no  problem .and i have see the rostopic echo /odom the value of x is right when i move the car forward. en ,i find the problem maybe in the package of robot_pose_ekf .bacause i don't understand the tf how to link the odom..........^_^??